# PowerShell loop using input variables

Tags: loops, powershell, exchange-server

First off, I'm a complete idiot when it comes to PowerShell/coding in general, so apologies if this is an overly simple question I'm asking.

I've got a script that I'm using to create distribution lists in exchange via PowerShell:

```
param($name,$user=$(throw "You must specify the name of the group"))
New-DistributionGroup -Name $name -OrganizationalUnit "XXX.com/Distribution Lists"
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$name" -Member "$user"
```

The first variable, $name, is the name of the group, and the second, $user, is the name of the user to add to the group.

Ideally I'd like to loop the adding of users so someone could evoke the script using `./script GROUPNAME User1 User2 User3 User4 User5`.

Could anyone shed any insight or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat `$user`, or rather `$users`, as an array:

```
$users | %{ Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$name" -Member $_ }
```

(there might be better ways of adding multiple users, but the above should get you started.)

The script can be called like:

```
.\script GROUPNAME User1,User2,User3
```

Comment: Getting closer. It picks up the $user variable now as "User1 User2" but now throwing Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Member'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
-- script --
param($name, [string[]]$users=$(throw "You must specify the name of the user(s)"))

New-DistributionGroup -Name $name -OrganizationalUnit "XXX.com/Distribution Lists" 
foreach($user in $users)
{
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $name -Member $user
}
```

Comment: you don't want to be creating the group for each user.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've just tried it out but it's only picking up the first name entered as the variable. For example, ./script GROUP User1 User2. It's picking up GROUP and User1 but ignoring User2

Comment: The users have to be specified comma separated e.g. `user1,user2,user3`.  That's how you specify an array argument to a PowerShell function.

Comment: @manojlds Thx for pointing that out.  Wasn't much paying attention to the actual contents of the script.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input gents, I appreciate it. So it seems like it's picking up the variables now: User is: taylor alan. Only issue is that it's only adding the first user to the group.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, I managed to get it going with your help.     param($name, [string[]]$users=$(throw "You must specify the name of the user(s)"))
    "Name is: $name"
    "User is: $users"
    New-DistributionGroup -Name $name -OrganizationalUnit "XXX/Distribution Lists" 
    foreach($user in $users)
    {
        Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$name" -Member "$user"
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can change the type of the Name parameter to accept multiple names and pipe those to the `Add-DistributionGroupMember` cmdlet:

```
param($name, [string[]]$users=$(throw "You must specify the name of the user(s)"))

$dg = New-DistributionGroup -Name $name -OrganizationalUnit "XXX.com/Distribution Lists" 
$users | Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $dg
```